# Magento IWD Onepage checkout - set default shipping method

Tags: php, magento, checkout

by default magento ( and this module ) show the shipping methods available only after the shipping form is filled..
but I need to show the methods on page load, before shipping infos. 
Is this possible? How?
I have try so many code, but i can't implement this.

Last one, but i don't know where to put this.

```
$shippingAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCountryId('UK')->setShippingMethod('matrixrate_matrixrate')-save();
```

Comment: Are your shipping methods dependent on delivery address.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to get all the shipping methods before filling in the shipping details.
In theory the shipping methods depend on the shipping details.
So even if you all the shipping methods you will get wrong prices.
And this is bad for business.
If the customer sees for example at first: `Some shipping method: 5$`, then he fills in his shipping address and sees: `Some shipping method: 15$` there is a big chance he will stop the checkout.

But I wrote this answer so I can recommend you not to use the IWD checkout extension. [Here is why](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146).
To summarize what I answered for that question:

- the extension sends your data to their servers.
- if their server is offline, your checkout will probably stop working.

Comment: You're right of course, but this is very useful for when the shipping method (and price) isn't dependent on the customers shipping address - which is true for *a lot* of cases. Many stores that operate in only one country have one shipping method with one price.
Edit: although actually, in the current question @Ste is setting the shipping method to Webshopapps matrixrate, which of course is dependent on the postcode.. I don't see that working...

Comment: Hi Marius, Is it possible for one shipping method? we have freeshipping_freeshipping which i want to display when page load.